# Angular2 convert hex to file and display it

Tags: angular, encryption

I need to display an image sent by a serve. My angular2 app receives a `hex string` which I convert to a `byteArray`, then to `blob`, then to `file`. In my console.log i see the converted file:

```
File(1975561) {name: "uploaded_file.jpg", lastModified: 
    1528145682995, lastModifiedDate: Mon Jun 04 2018 16:54:42 GMT-040....
```

But when I try to display it, it's not working. Shows just an image icon. 
[image]

The same thing happens if I open it in a new window. 
I checked whether hex string is correct in hex-to-file online converter and I got the correct file. So my hex is correct.
My code is:

```
Service:
public hexToFile(hex): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    let bytes = [];
    for ( let i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2) {
      bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    }
    let blob = new Blob(bytes, { type: "image/jpeg" });
    let file = new File([blob], "uploaded_file.jpg", {type: "image/jpeg", lastModified: Date.now()});
    observer.next(file);
  });
}

Component:
public showFile(hex) {
    let _self = this;
    this.service.hexToFile(hex).subscribe(file => {
      let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      _self.sanitizedUrl = _self.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
    });
}


<div *ngIf="image">
  <img src=`{{sanitizedUrl}}` width="500px"/>
</div>
```

Comment: `src='{{sanitizedUrl}}'` Are those back ticks in your HTML? If so the html will not be happy with that you need to change those to double or single quotes, preferably double in HTML.

Comment: @Narm thanks, I changed to regular quotes. But it wasn't the cause of my issue. Even if I remove the code from http and make a file opened in a new window or download, I get the error that file was damaged and can't be displayed.